# Table column re-sizing using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am trying to write a piece of code that enables column re-sizing  functionality to my data table.But its not working properly.. I explored on internet for couple of days but I could find nothing except  some plug-ins. But I don't want to use  any plug-in, since my data table is very complicated and if I use them the other functionalities of the table may be destroyed.Thus I tried to write my own. Can you please check and refine my code or suggest any other code that fulfills my spec....
**Note:** User can re-size the column towards right upto table width but towrds left, its upto   td's left position only..
**Eidt:** Maxwell has given a great alternative..It works fine but in one case.If I try to resize towards left side, its not allowing since td width is fixed to it's content width...But I want to re-size it to left side upto it's its *offset().left* value by putting td's style to overflow:hidden or some other way....

Here is my piece of code....

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC>
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>
  table{
   border-collapse:collapse;
  }
  table td{
    border:1px solid red;
  }
  .vUiDtColResize{
   width:2px;
   height:20px;
   border:1px solid blue;
   float:right;
   display:block;
   cursor:w-resize;
   position:relative;
   right:-3px;
   float:top;
  }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <td>S.No   <div class="vUiDtColResize"></div></td>
     <td>Name   <div class="vUiDtColResize"></div></td>
     <td>Qualif <div class="vUiDtColResize"></div></td>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr> <td>1</td><td>Rama Rao</td><td>M.C.A</td></tr>
      <tr> <td>2</td><td>Dushyanth</td><td>B.Tech</td></tr>
      <tr> <td>3</td><td>AnandKumar</td><td>M.C.A</td></tr>
      <tr> <td>4</td><td>Veera Reddy</td><td>B.Tech</td></tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <div id="helper"></div>
 </body>
 <script>
  $('.vUiDtColResize').each(function(){

     var _rsTd = $(this).parent('td');
     var _rsTr = _rsTd.parent('tr');
     var _rsTdRight,_thisLeft,_rsTdWidth;

     $(this).draggable({axis:'x',containment:_rsTd,refreshPositions:true,
         create:function(event,ui){
         },
         start:function(event,ui){
         _rsTdRight = _rsTd.offset().left + _rsTd.outerWidth();
         },
         drag:function(event,ui){
           var _sizeDiff = $(this).offset().left - _rsTdRight;
           _rsTdRight = $(this).offset().left;
          _rsTdWidth = _rsTd.outerWidth() + _sizeDiff;
          _rsTd.outerWidth(_rsTdWidth);
         },
         stop:function(event,ui){
         }
     });
  });

 </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After had been exploring in internet for couple of days, I got a good code,which was modified by me to make it satisfies my requirement as well( Of course, my change is bit little.It might be useful to somebody else,so I am posting here...
***style***

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="E:\Examples\BSP\BSPExtensions\jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css"/>
<style>

table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;   
}
tr.last td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

td {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    text-align: left;
    overflow:hidden;
}

td.last {
    border-right: none;
}
thead td div:first-child{
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  overflow:hidden;
}
tbody td div:first-child{
  overflow:hidden;
}

.scrollContainer {
    overflow:auto;
    width:700px;
    height:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid red;
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .resizeHelper,.ui-resizable-e {
        position: relative;
        float: right;       
    }
}
</style>
```

***Script***

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
 /**
 * Enables resizable data table columns.
 **/

(function($) {
   $.widget("ih.resizableColumns", {
       _create: function() {
            this._initResizable();
        },

        _initResizable: function() {

            var colElement, colWidth, originalSize;
            var table = this.element;

            this.element.find("thead td").resizable({
                handles: {"e": ".resizeHelper"},
                minWidth: 2, // default min width in case there is no label
                // set correct COL element and original size
                start:function(event, ui) {
                    var colIndex = ui.helper.index() + 1;
                    colElement = table.find("thead > tr > td.ui-resizable:nth-child(" + colIndex + ")");
                    colWidth = parseInt(colElement.get(0).style.width, 10); // faster than width
                    originalSize = ui.size.width;
                },                

                // set COL width
                resize: function(event, ui) {
                    var resizeDelta = ui.size.width - originalSize;                    
                    var newColWidth = colWidth + resizeDelta;
                    colElement.width(newColWidth);

                    // height must be set in order to prevent IE9 to set wrong height
                    $(this).css("height", "auto");
                }
            });
        }

    });

    // init resizable
    $("#MyTable").resizableColumns();
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

***Your html is to be like:****

```
<div class="scrollContainer">
    <table class="resizable" id="MyTable" width="100%">
         <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="ui-resizable" style="width:100px;">
                <div>
                    <span >Column 1</span>
                    <div class="resizeHelper ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
                </div>
                </td>
                <td class="ui-resizable" style="width:200px;">
                <div>
                    <span >Column 2</span>
                    <div class="resizeHelper ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
                </div>
                </td>
                <td class="ui-resizable" style="width:300px;">
                <div>
                    <span >Column 3</span>
                    <div class="resizeHelper ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
                </div>
                </td>

                <td class="ui-resizable" style="width:150px;">
                <div>
                    <span >Column 4</span>
                    <div class="resizeHelper ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
                </div>
                </td>
                <td class="ui-resizable" style="width:200px;">
                <div>
                    <span >Column 5</span>
                    <div class="resizeHelper ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
                </div>
                </td>
                <td class="ui-resizable last" style="width:100px;">
                <div>
                    <span >Column 6</span>
                    <div class="resizeHelper ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
                </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td><div>Column 1</div></td><td><div>Column 2</div></td>
                <td><div>Column 3</div></td><td><div>Column 4</div></td>
                <td><div>Column 5</div></td><td><div>Column 6</div></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="last">
                <td><div>Column 1</div></td><td><div>Column 2</div></td>
                <td><div>Column 3</div></td><td><div>Column 4</div></td>
                <td><div>Column 5</div></td><td><div>Column 6</div></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I merged your code with some techniques that I found — http://jsfiddle.net/tpqn7/

IMHO, there are still some problems. First of all I suppose it's would be better (also easier) if table headers can be re-sized by pressing each TH, no only small border.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks,it some what meets my spec...Can't we decrease the width of the td to 0 or 1px on dragging left side.Currently I could drag it up to table td's largest text width...I want that td can be collapsed up to its left position by overflow:hidden of the td content.....

Comment: For this you can play with `position: absolute; overflow: hidden` etc.
But in this case, maybe it is better to use existing libraries? Because of writing your own is always going trough the same problems, that has been already solved by library authors.

Comment: position:absolute for what?....I played with overflow:hidden,but it didn't help..Can you please check it once...One more thing my table cell may contain input box/image or any thing...